# Wordpress functions in custom file

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have been attempting to get wordpress functions running in a standalone PHP file. According to wordpress is should be a simple case of adding the following line:

```
require( dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/vendor/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Where 'dirname(dirname(dirname(**FILE**))) . '/vendor/wordpress/' is the location of my wordpress install. But this returns the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp() in /vendor/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php on line 16
```

I have also tried:

```
require( dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/vendor/wordpress/wp-load.php');
```

But this isnt able to indentify any functions, such as:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_recent_posts() in index.php on line 30
```

I've not been able to find any answers online, please help :/

Comment: Can you say your full path of that file?

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is your file is not loaded where you have include.

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php';
```

Please try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I used this to target the correct location: require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../vendor/wordpress/wp-load.php'); but it returned the same error. Thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

If your file is in within wordpress directory means, use like below..

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');
```

or

If ur file is not within wordpress directory, use like this,

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/wordpress/wp-load.php';
```

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who help me to find the solution to the problem. In this instance the issue was the setting for the ABSPATH in the wp-config.php file. Due to the wordpress directory being separate from the config file, the ABSPATH needed to be updated to correctly point to the wordpress directory:

```
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/vendor/wordpress/' );
```

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else.